# Many QPropertyAnimation instances VS single one?

Tags: c++, qt, animation, cross-platform

I use `QPropertyAnimation` simply as a source of ticks. I set 1 sec animation, infinite number of loops, call `start()` and then watch QElapsedTimer::elapsed() in a "tick handler" to know how much time is elapsed from animation start. So, i don't depend on loops count, animation start and stop values, and i don't care about property value that is being animated. Just a source of ticks!

Before that i was using `QTimer` that gives different results on Linux and Windows: for animation to be smooth in Linux, i had to use `QTimer` interval = 1000/30, but for windows 1000/60 was a minimum. So i had to use #ifndef, but that's a dirty code. In addition to that, QTimer uses signal-slot machinery, but QPropertyAnimation doesn't, so my QApplication event loop is not busy with animation events (am i correct?)

Now i need to animate `N` widgets (different kind of animation for each), and i am going to use QPropertyAnimation in the same way - as the same stupid source of ticks.

What is the CPU-cost difference between these variants:

- `N` running `QPropertyAnimation` instances each connected to its own widget; Qt documentation say that `QPropertyAnimation` fire ticks at about 60fps = ~17 ms between ticks. But Qt cannot fire ticks from `N` different `QPropertyAnimation` instances simultaneously, because you may have started these animations in different time() - lets say there was 8 ms between `QPropertyAnimation::start()`.
- 1 single running `QPropertyAnimation` instance connected to some kind of proxy object that transmit the ticks to `N` widgets; And all such widgets have a member 'animTick(void)' for that.

Comment: Based on your posts, I'm afraid that what you're trying to do is hopelessly convoluted and goes against many Qt idioms. Is this for an open source project? If so, could you give a link to the repository?

Comment: @KubaOber http://sourceforge.net/projects/audigger/

Comment: I've started a chatroom about that.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a source of "ticks", then all you need is a `QVariantAnimation`, not even `QPropertyAnimation`.

The more animations, the higher the CPU cost. All you want is *one* animation, whose `valueChanged(QVariant)` signal is connected to multiple widgets.

Note that a `QBasicTimer` is not a source of anything, it's a very thin wrapper around the timer id returned by `QObject::startTimer()`. Thus it only works within a `QObject` instance, and only when you reimplement `timerEvent(...)`.

The `QVariantAnimation` is simply a source of nicely timed ticks so that you don't need to reinvent the wheel.

If you want a general purpose timer that sends signals to multiple objects, you really want a `QTimer`. That's what it's for. That way you don't need proxy objects, as you can connect one signal to many slots. You can also connect a signal to a signal, if you so wish - thus you can forward or alias signals. A `QTimer` is simply a `QObject` with `timerEvent(...)` that emits a signal. That's all there's to it. It'd be silly to write your own.

Comment: As i understand, i need QBasicTimer for ticks, not even any kind of Q***Animation class. But if i need 100 animations, i would prefer 1 QBasicTimer and 1 proxy-object to transmit ticks to 100 QObjects, because more QBasicTimers, more CPU load...

Comment: No, if you want a source of timed signals, you want a `QTimer`, and no proxies. I'm sure of that. `QBasicTimer` is a micro-optimization if you want a source of ticks within a `QObject`.

Comment: but QBasicTimer is more lightweight! Not so lightweight? But it does not even uses SIGNAL-SLOT, so main event loop doesn't do useless job 60 times a second!

Comment: If you use a QBasicTimer to emit a signal, this is equivalent to using a QTimer. That's all a QTimer does. Just look at the source of QTimer and see for yourself. If you think that something is causing performance penalty, you better had profiler dumps to show it to be the case. Otherwise you're just fantasizing about things. The audigger code shows that, I'm afraid - a lot of micro-optimizations that have zero basis in fact.

Comment: as i understand, QBasicTimer can kick QObject without emitting any signal. I have no profiler evidences for my ideas. And i 99% agree with you that i will not get any notable performance penalty with QTimer. Remaining 1% is my preferences of micro-optimizations :)

Comment: Yes, QBasicTimer simply calls `startTimer()` on a QObject instance. You then intercept it in `timerEvent()`. But if you then want to distribute this "event" to multiple objects, doing it via signal-slot connections is the easiest thing ever. Parameter-less connections are very fast.

Comment: i see. If you'd like, you can post somewhere a little article about the most terrible crimes in audigger source code. I will pay a lot of attention to such kind of article (-;